# if f and g are monotonically increasing functions, such that f(g(n))=O(n) and f(n)=Ω(n) then g(n)=O(n)

Tags: functions, asymptotics, computer-science

I have to prove this statement :
if $f$ and $g$ are monotonically increasing functions, such that $f(g(n))=O(n)$ and $f(n)=Ω(n)$ then $g(n)=O(n).$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you [edit] your question to include your thoughts and efforts on this problem? What have you tried, and where are you having difficulty? This will help people write an appropriate answer the addresses your problem. Questions that include this information tend to have a much better response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By truncating the functions we can assume that the starting indices are $0$. That is,
$$ \exists c,c_0 > 0\mid \forall n \in \mathbb{W}, f(g(n)) \leq c n, f(n) \geq c_0 n
$$
Then we have
$$ c n \geq f(g(n)) \geq c_0 g(n)
$$
as desired.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply but i dont understand how you do this step : f(g(n))≥c0g(n) if you can datail more it will help me alot

Comment: @helpless1000 You know that $f(n) \geq c_0 n$ for all $n$, so substituting $n \mapsto g(n)$...